# How to unit-test code that uses python-multiprocessing

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, python-multiprocessing

I have some code that uses multiprocessing.Pool to fork workers and perform a task in parallel. I'm trying to find the *right way* to run unit tests of this code.

Note I am *not* trying to test serial code test cases in parallel which I know packages like nose support.

If I write a test function that tests said parallel code, and attempt to run the tests with nose via: `nosetests tests/test_function.py` the non-parallel test execute properly but the parallel tests fail when multiprocessing tries to fork because main is not importable:

```
      File "C:\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
AssertionError: __main__
    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
AssertionError:     _assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
_main__AssertionError
: __main__
```

Which just repeats until I terminate the task. I can run the tests successfully if I modify `tests/test_function.py` to include:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    nose.main()
```

and then execute with `python tests\test_function.py`

So what is the "right" way to do this that will integrate with a unit test package (doesn't have to be nose)?

Environ: Python 2.7.10 amd64 on Windows 7 64-bit

Update 2020: With python 3 and pytest, this is not an issue, suggest upgrades!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like (see http://7fttallrussian.blogspot.com/2014/04/fix-for-bug-with-unittest-and.html)

> There is a bug in all Pythons up to 2.7.6 (i.e. all 2.x so far, *April 17 2014*) that breaks using unittest and multiprocessing module on Windows. ... It's fixed in new Pythons 3.x but haven't been backported to 2.x yet

I see people advising:

- patch multiprocessing module itself (a blogpost from first link has a link to the patch. I currently cannot post more than two links here)
- or implement similar workaround in test module: [an example of workaround in a test](https://gist.github.com/Kerrigan29a/4f459c901a21951ad1bd)

A code (non-significantly modified) from "an example of workaround in a test":

```
import unittest
import sys
class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):

        # To fix the Windows forking system it's necessary to point __main__ to
        # the module we want to execute in the forked process
        old_main =                          sys.modules["__main__"]
        old_main_file =                     sys.modules["__main__"].__file__
        sys.modules["__main__"] =           sys.modules["app"]
        sys.modules["__main__"].__file__ =  sys.modules["app"].__file__

        # do your testing here

        sys.modules["__main__"] =           old_main
        sys.modules["__main__"].__file__ =  old_main_file
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried either of those solutions by myself (at least yet). I came across them, and this question, while trying to solve different problem. If I try any of those solutions, I'll amend this post.

Comment: A link to patch for python 2.7 mentioned in the answer: https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/c82588ca3a79. (couldn't include it in the answer, as currently I can use up to two links only)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to mock multiprocessing in unit tests using [python mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock). Because unit tests should be **independent** and **repeatable**. That's why usually I'm creating mock version of multiprocessing classes (`Process` and `Pool`). Just to be sure that my tests are executed in right manner.